# Flashplugin-installer fails to install (unable to download the .tar..gz file)

Tags: installation, apt, package-management, flash

I have had this "Failed to download package files" window popping up regarding flashplugin-installer for a long time now. I have tried "sudo apt-get remove --purge flashplugin installer" and then installing it again etc. to no avail, the window always pops back up and there is no libflashplayer.so anywhere. Apt-get says: flashplugin-installer: downloading http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_11.2.202.310.orig.tar.gz

Which does not seem to exist. Weirdly apt-get does not give off any errors when installing flashplugin-installer even though that file seems non-existant and the installation seems to fail since I get no libflashplayer.so anywhere. I have tried apt-get update but it does not help.

Why is apt-get trying to download a non-existant file and how can I fix this? I'd rather not install flash outside the package manager.

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem. I searched for an apt-cache query and went for a sudo apt install
`apt-cache search adobe-flash`

The query returned with a row about adobe flash plugin 11

so I went ahead and

`sudo apt-get install <relevant row>`

Worked fine for me.

Comment: Can't see anything related to "adobe-flash". There was a flashplugin-downloader (instead of installer) but it does not seem to work either.

Comment: How do I upload an image file from my system to this forum? Then I could share my query screen-shot with you and maybe we could work something out.

Comment: Meanwhile while I try to upload the image, try going for `sudo apt-get autoremove` followed by `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`. I remember, using `purge` instead of `remove` once, following that event whenever I tried to `upgrade` or `update`, my system returned errors and I was unable to download any more.
 After the update+upgrade event, try downloading again (using both aptitude and manual methods) and check if u have some luck looking forward to it.

Comment: This is what I get when I go for `apt-cache search`.

  ![term_shot](http://img286.imagevenue.com/img.php?image=334351550_Screenshot_122_247lo.jpg)